# Performance difference when doing string indexing using [0] and [0:1] on list, numpy and series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

## System Information

Python version : 3.7.12
Pandas version : 1.3.4
OS : Debian 10

## Background

I'm doing some experiment on the fastest way to extract first several letter of list/series of string and I notice some very weird behaviour of [ ]. Here's 3 different experiment I tried :

### 1. Analyzing performance of [0] compared to [0:1] on list comprehension

Let's say X is an array-like object. Then X[0] and X[0:1] must be doing the same thing.

But from this experiment:

```py
N = 1000000
list_str = ['ABC']*N
%timeit [x[0] for x in list_str]   # 37.8 ms ± 141 µs per loop 
%timeit [x[0:1] for x in list_str] # 69.7 ms ± 113 µs per loop

N = 10
list_str = ['ABC']*N
%timeit [x[0] for x in list_str]   # 592 ns ± 3.72 ns per loop
%timeit [x[0:1] for x in list_str] # 956 ns ± 6.29 ns per loop
```

The x[0] is almost **60%-90%** faster than x[0:1], which is quite weird. This indicating that [0] and [0:1] is not doing the same thing behind the scenes even if it produces the same output.

### 2.  Analyzing performance of [0] compared to [0:1] on numpy array comprehension

I curious if using numpy array will yield different performance.

```py
N = 1000000
list_str = np.array(['ABC']*N)
%timeit [x[0] for x in list_str]  # 262 ms ± 9.95 ms per loop
%timeit [x[0:1] for x in list_str]# 293 ms ± 8.34 ms per loop

N = 10
list_str = np.array(['ABC']*N)
%timeit [x[0] for x in list_str]  # 3.61 µs ± 22.3 ns per loop
%timeit [x[0:1] for x in list_str]# 4.04 µs ± 58.7 ns per loop
```

The x[0] is faster only by around **10%** than x[0:1]

### 3.  Analyzing performance of [0] compared to [0:1] on string indexing with `.str` accessor on pandas' series.

On pandas, we can use .str[n] to get the n-th element of each member on the series. The experiment goes like this:

```py
N = 1000000
series = pd.Series(['ABC']*N)
%timeit series.str[0]   # 388 ms ± 10.5 ms per loop
%timeit series.str[0:1] # 172 ms ± 712 µs per loop

N = 10
series = pd.Series(['ABC']*N)
%timeit series.str[0]   # 131 µs ± 2.02 µs per loop 
%timeit series.str[0:1] # 133 µs ± 4.25 µs per loop
```

On this case, [0:1] is over 50% than [0] approach on long series.

## Question

I thought that [0] and [0:1] doing the same thing, but from this experiment it is already clear that [0] and [0:1] can give **significant** difference in speed. So, what do I miss in here? Is because of the data structure? Or [0] and [0:1] just simply not same?

Comment: `0` isn't a slice, just an int. `0:1` is the slice. They only give the same value on a string because a string itself is effectively a container of strings, you'd see a difference between e.g. `[1, 2, 3][0]` and `[1, 2, 3][0:1]`.

Comment: ohhh okay, i will fix my question then. thanks

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question. Isn't it quite obvious that `[0]` and `[0:1]` are not the same? One is indexing, the other one is slicing. Even if in some certain cases what you get is the same, that's not the case in all the cases, because those two things are not the same, thus explaining the difference in performance. The only thing I believe you're missing is that just because two operations sometimes return the same values it doesn't mean that they're doing the same, but I would think that much is evident.

Comment: Your array example exhibits the same time difference, 30ms, but the ratios are different because array iteration is so much slower.  The `pandas` is complicated by its own iteration method.